# How to customize Dropdown Button and items in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout, flutter-dropdownbutton

Today I tried to design a dropdown button with customized items in it where I can select all items or deselect all items with one click. But I didn't understand the approach how to do it. So please help me guys how to approach the required design and below I placed my design and required design.
[image: design]
and here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String dropdownvalue = 'Apple';

  var items =  ['Apple','Banana','Grapes','Orange','watermelon','Pineapple'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DropDownList Example"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("DropDownButton"),
                Container(
                  height: 40,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.grey, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 0.80),
                  ),
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      elevation: 0,
                      value: dropdownvalue,

                      icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

                      items:items.map((String items) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: items,
                            child: Text(items)
                        );
                      }
                      ).toList(),

                      onChanged: (String? newValue){
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                        });
                      },

                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This should help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650773/flutter-i-want-to-show-dropdown-list-under-dropdown-flutter/70651433#70651433

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dropdown_button2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) package for this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String dropdownvalue = 'Apple';
  var items = [
    'Apple',
    'Banana',
    'Grapes',
    'Orange',
    'watermelon',
    'Pineapple'
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DropDownList Example"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("DropDownButton"),
                Container(
                    height: 40,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 0.80),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: DropdownButton2(
                        hint: Text(
                          'Select Item',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        items: items
                            .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: item,
                                  child: Text(
                                    item,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ))
                            .toList(),
                        value: dropdownvalue,
                        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                          });
                        },
                        buttonHeight: 40,
                        buttonWidth: 140,
                        itemHeight: 40,
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

final result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying, but your code doesn't meet my requirement and I don't want to rely on packages. If you have any other approach please post. Thankyou

Comment: No problem, as far as I know, you will either have to make a custom drop down widget or use the package shown above to get the desired results.